# Nginx Reverse Proxy with back-end .net core using signalR

Tags: c#, .net, nginx, signalr, ubuntu-server

I have a web server running asp.net core using signalR that I have trouble communicating with.

My Nginx default setup looks like this:

```
server_name example.com www.example.com;

#FrontEnd
location / {            
root /var/www/app/frontend/dist;
}

#BackEnd
location ~ /(Lobby|Room|Channel|test) {
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
proxy_set_header   Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

I am trying to route all /Lobby, /Room, /Channel requests to my asp.net web server running kestrel.

My service for my backend server is configured like this:

```
[Service]
User=root
Group=root
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/app/backend/app
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/app/backend/app/Backend.dll
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
```

Lastly my startup.cs looks like this.

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options => {
options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
            });
services.AddSignalR();
            
services.AddCors(CorsConfig.Configure); 

=== Policy ==== 
options.AddPolicy(AllowKnownClientOriginsCorsPolicy,
builder =>
{
   builder.AllowAnyMethod()
   .AllowAnyHeader()
   .WithOrigins(
   "http://example.com",
   "https://example.com")
   .AllowCredentials();
});


==== CONFIGURE ====

app.UseCors(CorsConfig.AllowKnownLocalClientOriginsCorsPolicy);

app.UseForwardedHeaders();

app.UseRouting();
```

When trying to access the backend from my front-end application I get an error in my console that looks like this:

**
Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': null

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://example.com/Lobby?id=XF76OkXbJu6e3SwC_daRgw.

Error: Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled.
**

Please help me contacting my backend server through signalR via those mentioned routes.
I am not sure if the error is from Nginx settings or Startup.cs

It is worth mentioning that the server is being run on a remote server.

Comment: Check [this article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/).